# How to use the random function for producing different flows in Cplex

Tags: networking, network-programming, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I am implementing the mathematical model in cplex that I have a set of different types of Network Functions(NFs) that can be used to generate different flows. For example, {V11, V12, V31} produce a flow. I want 20 different flows, where each flow consists of a set of chains of length 2 to 4 that contain Network Functions. In other words, each flow consists of several chains that include different functions. Now, my problem is that The random function in cplex cannot select functions randomly and generate flows for me. Please help me, Many thanks.

```
{string} V = {"V11", "V12", "V13", "V21", "V22", "V23", "V31", "V32", "V41", "V42", "V43", 
"V51", "V52", "V53"};

range F=1..20;

{string} Flow[f in F] ={rand(b) | b in V};

execute
{ writeln(Flow); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me use [randompick](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/randompick.mod) as a start.

And in your case this gives

```
{string} V = {"V11", "V12", "V13", "V21", "V22", "V23", "V31", "V32", "V41", "V42", "V43", 
"V51", "V52", "V53"};

range F=1..20;

int sizeFlow[f in F]=2+rand(3); 

int n=card(V);
int m=4;

range r=1..n;

        // scripting way that will get m times 1

        range subr=1..m;
        int t[f in F][i in subr]=1+rand(n+1-i);
        {int} setn[f in F]=asSet(r);

        int x2[F][i in r];

        execute
        {
        for (var f in F) for(var i in subr)
        {
           var e=t[f][i];
           var e2=Opl.item(setn[f],e-1);
           x2[f][e2]=1;
           setn[f].remove(e2);
        }
        }
        
        {int} result[f in F]={i | i in r:x2[f][i]==1};
        
{string} Flow4[f in F]=union (i in result[f]) {item(V,i-1)};
        
{string} Flow[f in F]={item(Flow4[f],j-1) | j in 1..sizeFlow[f]};

assert forall(f in F) forall(ordered i,j in Flow[f]) i!=j;
        
execute
{
  writeln(Flow);
 }
```

which can give

```
 [{"V12" "V13" "V21" "V22"} {"V31" "V41" "V51" "V53"} {"V11" "V21" "V41" "V52"}
         {"V11" "V21"} {"V11" "V22"} {"V41" "V42"} {"V31" "V41" "V52"} {"V22"
         "V32" "V43" "V51"} {"V22" "V42" "V51" "V52"} {"V42" "V43" "V51" "V52"}
         {"V13" "V22"} {"V13" "V31" "V32" "V42"} {"V22" "V23"} {"V12" "V32"
         "V51" "V53"} {"V11" "V12"} {"V22" "V32" "V43"} {"V22" "V41"} {"V22"
         "V42" "V51"} {"V21" "V43" "V51" "V53"} {"V11" "V31" "V42" "V53"}]
```

for instance

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I added your code to my main code, but now the main problem that exists in my entire code is how to use the created flow as an index for parameters and decision variables. For example, int Dflow[Flow]=...; or dvar boolean I[V][Nunode1][Flow][jf]; these codes have this error "No range for types int{int}F". Can you help me in this matter, please? Thank you in advance.